# Google Sheets Auto Copy, Paste, Delete

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know a script that would let me copy data from cells A3:E1000 on Sheet1  and paste it to Sheet2.  After pasting I need it to delete the exact data that it copied from Sheet1 (Sheet2 will still have copied data) and I need it to do this everyday at 11:30pm.  I need Sheet2 to be able to keep taking the data forever as a digital archive of the data that is being copied daily from Sheet1.  I hope this makes sense.  I can't figure it out.  When I run this it works if I run dailyLog and then run clearRange separately.  When I run autoArchive it deletes the data from Info sheet but doesn't paste it into the Archive sheet.

```
function autoArchive(){
dailyLog();
clearRange();
}

function dailyLog() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getSheetByName("Info");
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Info');
var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 2, 1), {contentsOnly: false});
}

function clearRange() {
   var sheetActive = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getSheetByName("Info");
  var start, end;
  start = 2;
  end = sheetActive.getLastRow() - 1;
  sheetActive.deleteRows(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind there is  a limit to the number of cells per sheet. I believe it's 400,000.

Comment: Ok.  So I thought that I figured it out, but it doesn't work exactly like I want.  It will work if I manually run the function one at a time.  When I try to run the both via "autoArchive" function it deletes that cells but doesn't copy the data.

Comment: @Cooper From https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en `Spreadsheets: Up to 5 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.` (from review)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` to force Google Apps Script to apply the changes made so far.

Example:

```
function autoArchive(){
  dailyLog();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  clearRange();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [record macro](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) function it will generate Google Apps Script for you. Just records the steps you take and give it a name so you only need to click the macro in the menu or use a shortcut.

@Cooper the current limit for a spreadsheet is 5.000.000 cells. Doesn't matter if it is in one sheet or all sheets together. However this might be increased in the nearby future.

Comment: I need it to happen automatically every night.  Can macros do that?  I did the macro, but I can't seem to find the script that it generated to see if I can manipulate it to do what I need.